# UPI Deep Link - Unable to complete the transaction

Tags: android, upi

[image]

Trying to connect the UPI payment using deeplink for my Android application, but every-time it fails at the last step.

The code fragment for the UPI payment call is below:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            URI_URL = getUPIString("xxx@upi", "xxx xxx", "test_101", "Test Transaction", "10", "INR");

            //Creating an intent for the UPI APP
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(URI_URL));
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay the MSME by");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null);
            }
        }
    });
```

To frame the UPI String using this function:

```
       private String getUPIString(String payeeAddress, String payeeName, String trxnRefId,
                            String trxnNote, String payeeAmount, String currencyCode) {
    String UPI = "upi://pay?pa=" + payeeAddress + "&pn=" + payeeName
            + "&tr=" + trxnRefId
            + "&tn=" + trxnNote + "&am=" + payeeAmount + "&cu=" + currencyCode;
    return UPI.replace(" ", "+");
}
```

What could be the possible reasons of failure? Any suggestion or help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is **T04** meaning the refId should be **alphanumeric with minlength 1 and maxlength 35**. instead of test_101 use test101.

Comment: Thanks Albin the issue is resolved now, do we have any official documentation related with error code and expected response from the intent? If you could share any link that would be great.

Comment: I wont be able to provide any links to that. Those are confidential docs shared by the banks. Please feel free to ask if you are stuck at any point.

Comment: you can refer this doc 
https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/circular/Circular18_BankCompliances_to_enbaleUPIMerchantecosystem_0.pdf 

All the Bank PSP apps and other payment apps are following this standard.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Albin.

One major issue I am facing right now is that every-time I complete the transaction or come back from the UPI app (TEZ, BHIM) the result code is "-1". How do we understand whether the transaction was success or failure?

Comment: Can you try the same from Chillr app and verify here

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on UPI and integrate it into my Android project. I have also created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/codetgh/MerchantUpiPayment) which can be useful for you.

Using deep linking, You will get mostly UPI supporting app but the problem is all app doesn't return value properly. I have tested Paytm, Google pay and freecharge and many more. But These app return value very well. 
Due to this problem, I have created custom intent chooser so that exclude those apps who don't return value after payment. Along with this, you will get code of QR code to generate and scan UPI QR code.

Want to know more, here is a [document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15h_Mom1Y7abJJIibUuC2Qjl1gh5LE97U).

Do check it and let me know, it helps you or not. Problem ask me.